# swift getting all values of a dictionary and passing to viewcontroller using almaofire

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

Hi have an application which collects data from an api and I use Alamofire and swiftyJSON. the current challenge I am facing now is that I have different dictionaries in one array and I want to be able to retun back specific items in the dictionary. this is the array I am working with

**Json**

```
[
    {
        "images": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "original": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/products/2018/05/f3.jpg",
                "caption": "",
                "display_order": 0,
                "date_created": "2018-05-26T17:24:34.762848Z",
                "product": 13
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "original": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/products/2018/05/f5.jpg",
                "caption": "",
                "display_order": 1,
                "date_created": "2018-05-26T17:24:34.815214Z",
                "product": 13
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "original": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/products/2018/05/f2.jpg",
                "caption": "",
                "display_order": 2,
                "date_created": "2018-05-26T17:25:19.117271Z",
                "product": 13
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "original": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/products/2018/05/f4.jpg",
                "caption": "",
                "display_order": 3,
                "date_created": "2018-05-26T17:25:19.155159Z",
                "product": 13
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

get a single image is like this

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADER).responseJSON { (response) in

        if response.result.error == nil {

            guard let data = response.data else {return}
            do {

                if let json = try JSON(data: data).array {
                    for item in json {

 let images = item["images"][0]["original"].stringValue


 ....
```

this returns only the indexed image.[0] if it is set to [1] it returns the indexed image at 1.

how do I return all the images so that I can loop through all and display in a collection view controller. more codes would be supplied on request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dit it Like that :

```
if let json = try? JSON(data: data).arrayValue {


        for item in json {
            let imagesList = item["images"].arrayValue

            let imagesURL = imagesList.map {$0["original"].string}.compactMap({$0})
             if imagesURL.count > 0{
                print( imagesURL[0])
            }


        }
    }
```

**Or:**

```
do {
            let json  = try JSON(data: data).array

            json?.forEach({ (item) in
                let imagesList = item["images"].arrayValue

                let imagesURL = imagesList.map {$0["original"].string}.compactMap({$0})
                  if imagesURL.count > 0{
                print( imagesURL[0])
                }
            })
  } catch  {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: error `Value of type '[String?]' has no member 'compactMap'`

Comment: make sure that you write  correct code                 `let imagesURL = imagesList.map {$0["original"].string}.compactMap({$0})`

Comment: if you want to remove compact map  remove this  `.compactMap({$0})`

Comment: I removed the .compactMap({0}) and it works but how do I now pick a specified image from the array of images returned?

Comment: What is your need  `imagesURL` now is `[String?]`  String array

Comment: when I do `print(imagesURL[0])` the image at index 0 is printed but the app crashes immediately with error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`

Comment: please share your code after you write the solution above to be able to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171844/discussion-between-king-and-abdelahad-darwish).

Comment: just check index before your print  ` if imagesURL.count > 0{
                    print( imagesURL[0])
                }`